# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jPlayer'

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jplayer, typeerror

I'm working with RoR and I added a JPlayer from JQuery to my project.
I added it in the folder assets and in the html i have this:

```
<title>jPlayer as an audio player</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <link href="/jPlayer/skin/pink.flag/jplayer.pink.flag.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
                ready: function () {
                    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3"});
                },swfPath: "js",supplied: "mp3",wmode: "window"

            });
        });
        //]]>
    </script>
```

But I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jPlayer'

in this line: `$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({`

O added the corresponding gems to the Gem file, so I don't know what could be wrong. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: have you included required JS files on your page?

Comment: Make sure your JPlayer scripts are included in that page.

Comment: how can I include/require the scripts and the JS files? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Be sure your script is being pulled into the page, one way to check is by using the 'sources' tab in the Chrome Debugger/FireFox Firebug and searching for the file.
2. Be sure that you've included the script after you've included jQuery, as it is most certainly dependant upon that.
3. Make sure that you only have included a single jQuery library. Including multiple versions can cause problems.
4. If there is some other library which is overridding `$`, so your code is not working because `$` is not an alias for `jQuery` anymore. You can use `jQuery.noConflict()` to avoid conflicts with other libraries on the page which use the same variable `$`.

Comment: Hi Dasun, yes my script is being pulled, i checked. The point 2 means include this: <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>etc... and then the script? I don't get the point 3 which library should I include? And point 4, so now I can't use $? i'm just using $ in that pice of code.

Comment: I realised I don't have to include any library, because the library should be included inside </head> I don't develop it, rails does it, it looks for the file inside asset folder, it does it automatically.

Comment: @Dasun var `$ = jQuery.noConflict();` before my script helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Well after two days with this problem I solved it, i forgot to include this file `jquery.jplayer.min.js` in the `active_admin.rb`. It was just add:      `config.register_javascript 'jquery.jplayer.min.js'`

Small mistake but took lots of time!